# Exception guidance

Tags: c#

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Throwing an exception on this line:

```
AnnuityReader.WriteLine(fields[0] + "," + fields[1] + "," + fields[3] + "," + fields[4]);
```

I know there are some similar posts out here which have been resolved, but I have not figured it out yet. Any input is appreciated.

```
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    StreamWriter AnnuityReader;
    List<string[]> Accounts = new List<string[]>();
    private int x;

    private void Assignment2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string currentLine;
        string[] fields = new string[2]; 
        //Create streamreader
        StreamReader AnnuityReader = new StreamReader("annuities.txt");

        while (AnnuityReader.EndOfStream == false)
        {
            currentLine = AnnuityReader.ReadLine(); 
            fields = currentLine.Split(',');
            Accounts.Add(fields);
            cmbAccount.Items.Add(fields[0]);
        }
        AnnuityReader.Close(); //Creates dictionary

    }

    private void cmbAccount_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lstAccountDetails.Items.Clear();
        int index = cmbAccount.SelectedIndex;
        string[] fields;
        fields = Accounts[index];

        lstAccountDetails.Items.Add(String.Format("{0,10} {1,10}{2,10}", "Rate", "Deposit($)", "Value($)"));
        lstAccountDetails.Items.Add(String.Format("{0,10} {1,10:C}{2,10:C}", fields[1], double.Parse(fields[2]), double.Parse(fields[4])));

    }

    private void btnProcess_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lstAccountDetails.Items.Clear();
        double deposit;
        int index = cmbAccount.SelectedIndex;
        string[] fields = Accounts[index];

        try
        {
            deposit = double.Parse(txtDeposit.Text);
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Enter a positive number");
            txtDeposit.SelectAll();
            txtDeposit.Focus();
            return;
        }
        double currentValue = double.Parse(fields[4]);
        if (deposit > 0)
        {
            currentValue += deposit;

        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a positive number");

        fields[4] = currentValue.ToString();
        fields = Accounts[x];

        AnnuityReader.WriteLine(fields[0] + "," + fields[1] + "," + fields[3] + "," + fields[4]);
        lstAccountDetails.Items.Add(String.Format("{0,10} {1,10}{2,10}", "Rate", "Deposit($)", "Value($)"));
        lstAccountDetails.Items.Add(String.Format("{0,10} {1,10:C}{2,10:C}", fields[1], double.Parse(fields[2]), double.Parse(fields[4])));

        txtDeposit.Clear();
        AnnuityReader.Close();
    }
```

Comment: This answers your question. [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: If linked duplicate does not answer your question - please follow all debugging guidance in that question and then [edit] this post with really [MCVE].

Comment: That line has seven object references: `AnnuityReader`, `fields`, and `fields[0]` through `fields[4]`. One of those (at least) is null. Put a break point there, and when you reach the breakpoint check the values and find out which is `null`.

Comment: You need to skip empty lines in the .txt file.  if (fields.Length < 5) continue;

Answer (score 0):

Error is pretty clear. Object reference not set to an instance of an object. You are defining `StreamWriter AnnuityReader` but you are using that reference without setting to an object in `btnProcess_Click` function.

You can solve it in two ways. You need to set it to an instance in constructor or in your `btnProcess_Click` function before using. You can set it to an object like you did in `Assignment2_Load` function.

```
StreamReader AnnuityReader = new StreamReader("annuities.txt");
```